# javascript syntax questioon

Tags: javascript, if-statement, syntax

So let's say I have the following code:

```
function c (f,i) {
  let x = i;
  if (f(x,i)){
     x--;
  }
  if (f(x,2)) {
     console.log(1);
  }
  else {
     console.log(2);
  }
}
```

what exactly happens in the if statements, I don't understand the syntax behind it.
f is no function, it's a variable, so what happens here? does it equal to f * ( x * i)? whats the operands behind this syntax.
Thanks in advance

Comment: "f is no function, its a variable" - the two are not exclusive. Matter of fact, `f(x,i)` is a call expression, so unless `f` is a function, this will throw.

Comment: Actually, I'd assume that `f` is a function. You can pass functions to other functions in javascript

Comment: If 'f' is no function your code is bad and you will receive the error 'Uncaught TypeError: f is not a function'; if you need to pass 'f' as argument function look the @edwin suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variable can also hold a function. It's possible to call `c` like this:

```
c(function(x, i) {/* do some check with x and i */}, 10);
```

In the if statements, the function you pass is called to do a check. A function like this is called a callback function. You have to pass it to the `c` function as in the example above. So if you call `c`, you can also determine how the check is done that `c` does.